# Why is my signalR proxy info not generated correctly?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Ok so im using the latest version of signalR (2.10.0 at this moment in time) and I am adding a new hub to my application, I don't want to use it yet nor do I intend to in it's own right I simply want to use this hub to template some basic crud stuff so I don't have to rewrite it all the time.

The adding of this hub to my project causes signalR to fail and not correctly generate the proxy stuff on the client.

Can anyone explain why this would happen?

Here's my code ...

Existing hub:

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub { ... }
```

New hub:

```
public class Hub<T> : Hub { ... }
```

Client side code that breaks by adding new hub ...

```
$(function () {
        var notifications = $.connection.notificationHub;
        notifications.client.success = function (message) <--- js exception here
        { ... };  
});
```

The js exception reads "cannot read property client of undefined".

EDIT:

Looking closer at the details in chromes tools I can see that the client side error is due to : "`GET http://localhost/signalr/hubs 500 (Internal Server Error)`"

Question is, how do I fix this as attaching the debugger does not let me handle / see where this error is occurring.
I'm guessing this is in the signalR code somewhere.

Is there an issue with generics in signalR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ok ...

Since I never have any intention of actually creating a Hub only its sub types I made it abstract.

This appears to resolve the resolve the problem.

```
public abstract class Hub<T> : Hub { ... }
```